# Cannot read property 'uri' of null when install extenstion on vs code

Tags: vscode-extensions

Im trying to install extenstion "es7 react/Redux/React-Native snippets" in vs code, but then it failed, and pop up message: Cannot read property "**uri**" of null. Anybody get same problem? Please help